# Can I register a ng-template from outside of ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there anyway to programmatically add a ng-template to $templateCache.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
    I'm a template
</script>

<div id="appContainer" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-directive></my-directive>   
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var MyCtrl = blah;

var myDirective = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html'
    }
};

/* Register templates here??? */

angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective)
;

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('appContainer'), ['myApp']);
```

Since the template  is not under an ng-app, angular does not know it exists. The obvious thing is to not use angular.bootstrap, and put ng-app on the body, but I'm trying to design this module, so It could be nested in an existing ng-app, or used standalone. When its used in an existing ng-app, angular knows about it, but when its alone, angular doesnt know about the directive template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create your module, in the run function you can register a template like this:

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
   .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
   .directive('myDirective', myDirective)

 angular.module('myApp')
  .run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('myTemplate.html',
      'I\'m a template'
    );
  });
```